# Get the distinct value in descending order of timestamp from Elasticserch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am performing Elasticsearch operations in **Python**. I have following fields and data in **Elasticsearch index** -

```
sid member_id timestamp
1  1         2020-11-26T13:10:49.899Z
1  1         2020-11-25T14:10:49.899Z
1  2         2020-11-24T15:10:49.899Z
1  2         2020-11-25T16:10:49.899Z
```

Following is the mapping on these fields -

```
                                   "sid": {
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "raw": {
                                                "type": "keyword"
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "member_id": {
                                        "type": "integer",
                                        "fields": {
                                            "raw": {
                                                "type": "keyword"
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    },
                                    "timestamp": {
                                        "type": "date",
                                        "format": "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss.SSSZ"
                                    }
```

As a result, I want distinct member_id with latest timestamp as following -

```
member_id timestamp
1         2020-11-26T13:10:49.899Z
2         2020-11-25T16:10:49.899Z
```

Is it possible in Elasticsearch to get this result? If yes then please tell me how can I do it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) along with [max aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-max-aggregation.html) to achieve your required use case

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "sid": 1,
  "member_id": 1,
  "timestamp": "2020-11-26T13:10:49.899Z"
}
{
  "sid": 1,
  "member_id": 1,
  "timestamp": "2020-11-25T14:10:49.899Z"
}
{
  "sid": 1,
  "member_id": 2,
  "timestamp": "2020-11-24T15:10:49.899Z"
}
{
  "sid": 1,
  "member_id": 2,
  "timestamp": "2020-11-25T16:10:49.899Z"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
 {
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "member_id",
        "order": {
          "latestOrder": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latestOrder": {
          "max": {
            "field": "timestamp"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "unique_id": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.606396249899E12,
            "value_as_string": "2020-11-26T13:10:49.899Z"
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 2,
          "doc_count": 2,
          "latestOrder": {
            "value": 1.606320649899E12,
            "value_as_string": "2020-11-25T16:10:49.899Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```